# How to debug libgcc source in GDB? Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, gdb

I want to debug `libgcc_s.so.1` in GDB on the source level on Ubuntu 14.04.1. So I downloaded `libgcc1-dbg` and got the source of `gcc`.

In GDB, I use `directory` to specify the `gcc` source directory. But when I GDB some problem, and break in `libgcc_s.so.1`, I cannot get the source code.

```
Reading symbols from /home/love/pri...(no debugging symbols found)...done.

(gdb) directory ~/source/gcc-4.9/

Source directories searched: /home/lovelydream/source/gcc-4.9:$cdir:$cwd

(gdb) c

The program is not being run.

(gdb) run

Starting program: /home/lovelydream/prison

warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7ffa000

> 

Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.

0x00007ffff75e6350 in __read_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81

81  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: 没有那个文件或目录.

(gdb) b _Unwind_Find_FDE

Breakpoint 1 at 0x7ffff78d20c0

(gdb) c

Continuing.

x

Breakpoint 1, 0x00007ffff78d20c0 in _Unwind_Find_FDE ()

   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1

(gdb) info source

Current source file is ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S

Compilation directory is /build/buildd/eglibc-2.19/io

Source language is asm.

Compiled with DWARF 2 debugging format.

Does not include preprocessor macro info.

(gdb) ni

0x00007ffff78d20c2 in _Unwind_Find_FDE () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1

(gdb) directory ~/source/gcc-4.9/

Source directories searched: /home/lovelydream/source/gcc-4.9:$cdir:$cwd

(gdb) ni

0x00007ffff78d20c4 in _Unwind_Find_FDE () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1

(gdb) list

76  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: 没有那个文件或目录.

(gdb) list

76  in ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S

(gdb) list

76  in ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S

(gdb) info source
```

Comment: I can't help with `_Unwind_Find_FDE `, but `./sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S` is in glibc, not libgcc. To get source-level debugging for glibc, do `apt-get install libc6-dbg` and `apt-get source libc6` (which on Ubuntu 14.04 will actually install eglibc).

Comment: You need to have two versions (name them a bit differently) of GDB.  First the executable to be used as a tool for debugging and second, a version (compiled with -gdb3) that will be the version that is being debugged.

Comment: What do you mean by compiled with -gdb3?