# GDB on eclipse debug mode can't find stdlib/rand.c

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, debugging, gdb

I am trying to put the gdb to run with eclipse cdt on ubuntu to start debugging some simple programs. So I did the steps I reckon as necessary to get it running:

**1.** Create an executable project

**2.** Compile

**3.** Run

**4.** Create the file .gdbinit and place it on the main project folder

**5.** Set some of the debugger [configuration](http://nicolas.riousset.com/eclipse-how-to-debug-a-c-console-application-using-a-native-dos-console-instead-of-the-ide-integrated-one/):
[image]
[image]

**5.** I also tried to find a [.gdbinit](http://stephanfr.com/2012/10/23/debugging-gcc-in-eclipse-cdt-4-2/) file that would look some like this:

```
set schedule-multiple

dir ~/gcc_build/4.7.2/build/gcc
dir ~/gcc_build/4.7.2/gcc
dir ~/gcc_build/4.7.2/gcc/cp
dir ~/gcc_build/4.7.2/gcc/lto
source ~/gcc_build/4.7.2/build/gcc/gdbinit.in
```

But I didn't find anything similar in my computer, even after doing a:

```
# find / -name .gdbinit
```

So, my file .gdbinit end up with the simple content - yes only that:

```
set new-console on
```

Then I clicked on Apply and Debug:

[image]

The gdb starts working nicely as expected. I press the button "step over / F6" and the debugger goes jumping through the code step by step. Until the point it reaches the command rand() and the gdb hangs with the message:

```
Can't find a source file at "/build/buildd/eglibc-2.19/stdlib/rand.c" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.
```

[image]

Thus I also tried unsuccessfully to find the rand.c to update this path to include its location:

```
# find / -name rand.c
# find / -name stdlib
```

After the error message from GDB complaining that rand.c is missing, then I tried to keep stepping... since then the stepping mode is disable when I restart the debug:

[image]

Is this problem happening because some setting for my file .gdbinit is missing? Or some how GDB is not able to find the rand.c from stdlib from c99? When I compile and run the program it runs nicely. Only when I try to launch the debugger is when GDB crashes.

**Update:** I got the missing rand.c problem after running the [commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634788/how-to-debug-libgcc-source-in-gdb-ubuntu-14-04-1?rq=1):

```
# apt-get install libc6-dbg
# apt-get source libc6
```

But now a different error appears:

```
Can't find a source file at "/build/buildd/eglibc-2.19/csu/libc-start.c" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.
```

Should I also install that library for gdb?

All suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Cant you keep on stepping after that? Lire step out or step over

Comment: @Eric - thanks! is not doing any stepping.

Comment: This doesn't look like a crash, just a warning. What happens when you try to step?

Comment: I think it's like F6

Comment: F6 just like the icon for stepping on the GDB is not working.

Comment: The point is that it is normal not to have sources for all libraries. It happens all the time. gdb usually says that message in case you really wanted to debug stdlib, but you should be able to continue anyway. Worst case it will run asm and show the disassembly to you

Comment: Do you think might be something to get the stepping working again?

Comment: Do you check the chat?

Comment: @Eric - I got rid of the rand.c missing problem installing it with apt-get. See my update in my question. Now other similar error message appears instead.

Comment: If you click on the line that says core:3 does that enable stepping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I saw on your description... looking to the 4th and 5th image you posted, you did right all the required steps.

However, it seems to me that your GDB is attached to several projects. That means that unless you really need that, I would strongly advise you to select all project that you are not currently debugging and delete them from the debugger mode. So, my suggestion is that after you have done all the steps you did so far, then go on:

```
Debug Configurations > C/C++ Applications: (drop down it)
```

... then click on each project you are not compiling, with right button from the mouse select "delete" - but don't worry, it will not delete your project, but only the attachment of that project to your debugger mode.

Then restart the eclipse. When you again try to run in the debugger mode, everything will run much smoother than before.

Answer (score 0):

Step1:

Go to https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/ to download glibc.

Step2:

unzip it locally and whenever the eclipse prompts "Can't find ... xxx.c", just load the file into eclipse. It will work.